# C# Owin Auth - Common Token for the Webite and API

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api2, webapi

I have implemented the Owin Auth token approach in Web API(C#).

The question is, Can I use a common token for both Mobile App and the Website ?

If I create a token from the website and with this token can I authenticate a mobile app ?

If yes then how ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A website or mobile application can authenticate against an API using a JWT token, that should not be a problem if you have an API. In the API you typically use the AddJwtBearer() method to secure it.

However, you do not use the same token, instead you let the web and mobile client authenticate individually with the authentication provider (for example IdentityServer).